# Регулярное выражение для пробелов в тексте

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста с регулярным выражением, которое ищет места, где новое предложение начинается без пробела после точки. Допустим *hello.world* надо изменить на *hello. world* буквы могут быть как кириллица, так и латиница. Большие и маленькие, исключения - цифры, допустим *5.5* не должно меняться.
В голову пришел пока такой вариант:

```
/[.][а-яА-ЯA-Za-z]/
```

Но в его работу я не верю, иного алгоритма пока не удалось придумать.

Comment: А чего тут не верить. регулярка даст все перечисленные буквы после точки. (Возможно кроме буквы `ё`, потому что она не входит в диапазон а-я)

Comment: Набросал на коленке - попробуйте, может быть ещё подправить надо будет: `'~(?<=[a-zа-я])\.(?=[a-zа-я])~iu'`

Comment: @Erm это шаблон для прег_реплейс, и вторым параметром в ней надо передать пробел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы всё учтено:

```
$string = 'hello.world!Привет мир.123.123';
// hello. world! Привет мир. 123.123
echo preg_replace('~(?<=\p{L}\p{P})(?=\p{L}|\d)~iu', ' ', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если речь только про точки, то:

```
/\.\p{L}/
```

Если же нужны в том числе вопросительные и восклицательные знаки:

```
/(\.|\?|!)\p{L}/
```

Поиграться с регуляркой можно здесь: https://regex101.com/r/njwfPt/1